# Capture Value From Radio Button Group

Tags: vba, excel, radio-button

I am trying to capture the selected values stored in radio button groups.  For instance, I have two radio buttons (with no specific naming convention) grouped together with a group name of "1".  I wanted to know if there was a way to get which option was selected without having to specifically do IF elseif statements for the actual radio buttons themselves.

Ideally I would like the code to be able to say look at this optiongroup, retrieve the value for the text file and move to the next radio button group.

I am creating a survey where the results need to be captured into a .txt file.

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried using something like this when I was searching around the internet:
Select Case OptionGroup1.Value
  Case 1
    MsgBox "You chose Option 1"
  Case 2
    MsgBox "You chose Option 2"
End Select

Also I have tried some other codes as well, but I don't think I've really found anything that references the group correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to test the values of each radio button control item. The group only ensures that one (or zero) radio options are selected in that group. Keep in mind that it is possible that none of the options are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with groups specifically but here's how you can do it with frames (as far as I understand frames work similarly to groups with segregating options) on a userform.

- Name of the userform for this example is '**UF**'
- Name of **1st** frame that contains a number of options is '**Frame1**'
- Name of **2nd** frame that contains a number of options is '**Frame2**'

  ```
  'get the option selected within Frame1
  Dim opt as Control
  For Each opt in UF.Frame1.Controls
     If TypeName(opt) = "OptionButton" And opt = True Then
        x = MsgBox(opt.Caption) 'Outputs Caption of Selected Option in Frame1
     End If
  Next
  '----------------------------------------
  '----------------------------------------

  'and this would get the option selected within Frame2
  Dim opt as Control
  For Each opt in UF.Frame2.Controls
     If TypeName(opt) = "OptionButton" And opt = True Then
        x = MsgBox(opt.Caption) 'Outputs Caption of Selected Option in Frame2
     End If
  Next
  ```